# WPF Binding mvvm and code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Having a textbox, I want to send its text value to the view model:

```
<TextBox Name="txSourceText" Text="{Binding UploadFilePath,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the same time I want to set the value of the text box from a method from code behind:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofp = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofp.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        ofp.FilterIndex = 1;

        bool? userClickedOK = ofp.ShowDialog();

        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            //PathToFile = ofp.FileName;
            ***txSourceText.Text = ofp.FileName;***
        }

    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not set the view model value in the code behind?

Comment: I can't see why this code wouldnt work. as long as your datacontext of the textbox was correct

Comment: Yes, you are right. The code seems to work.

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought calling an event this way was not following the MVVM design pattern, it should be done using ICommand

Comment: Commands should be used here as David has mentioned.  Then move all this code for the OpenFileDialog to the viewmodel where you can both read and write to the UploadFilePath property which has two way binding.  As long as you raise the PropertyChanged event all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the `ICommand` interface and how to use a `Command` in MVVM.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example

1. Bind your TextBox to some `ViewModel` property
2. Create `Command` object with property change logic and then add to your `ViewModel` as a property
3. Bind you button to `Command` property

Answer (score 0):

You can send the text to property present in ViewModel by using TextBox_TextChanged event. In that event you can access the datacontext of the window, from that you can set the property for viewmodel

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = this.DataContext;
        (this.DataContext as ViewModel).MyProperty = text1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: This is just wrong, he already has two way binding in place to set the property in the viewmodel.